# asp.net placeholder in the head of a page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, placeholder

I have a page that includes javascript which I only want to run under certain conditions. To do this I have placed the scripts into an asp:placeholder

This actually seems to work but when I run a debug on the page I get the following warning.

*Element 'placeholder' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.*

If I move the placeholders into the body of the page the warning goes, but that means I'm left with scripts in the body which I also want to avoid. Does anyone have any hints on the best practice for this scenario?? thanks

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)

dim lt as new Literal()
lt.text = "<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/pageLoadAnimations.js'></scr" & "ipt>"
me.Header.Controls.Add(lt)

End Sub
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. I had not formatted the part about <head> to <head runat="server" id="header"> properly so it had been missed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include JS file straight from code behind:

```
If (some condition is true) Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "jquery-version.js")
End If
```

Comment: If there an alternative to this which allows me to add css files?

Comment: Ugly alternative, but yes: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "MyCss", "<link href=""StyleSheet.css"" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />", False)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways which fit your needs are:

Firstly, you could change your `<head>` tag to `<head id="header" runat="server">` then this allows you to dynamically add anything into it, e.g.

```
dim lt as new Literal()   
lt.text = "<script type='text/javascript' src='pathtojavascriptfile'></script>"  
me.Header.Controls.Add(lt)
```

Or you could create a Public string on your page, then stick the javascript in this.

Public _JS as string

Page_Load

```
_JS = "alert('here');" ' Or what ever your javascript is
```

ASPX Page

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-version.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $().ready(function(){
          <%=(me._JS) %>
       });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: what does the "me" part of your first suggestion do? That appears to be causing the page to error. I get the following: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: "Me" just refers to the current object. In this case Me is the Page class. So writing Me._JS refers to the Public variable _JS on the current page. Could you post the code you have so we can see where the error is coming from?

Comment: Check my answer again. didn't realise that I had not formatted my answer properly so it missed out a few key points.

Comment: For the record, I've accepted Shadow Wizard's answer as it's more elegant for adding scripts. Tim's answer also works though and is perfect if you're looking to add styles too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider looking into the ClientScriptManager. This will allow you to inject scripts into the header properly using whatever conditions you require.

[Including Custom Client Script in ASP.NET Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx#IncludingCustomClientScriptinASP.NETPages)
[ClientScriptManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx)